# Typescript - Object is possibly 'undefined' in interface

Tags: angular

In an Angular project, I am using an interface.

```
    export interface School {
      name: string = '';
      website: string;
      registrationNumber: string;
      dateEstablished: Date;
      address: string;
      country: [];
      companyLogo: any = '';
    
        clear() {
          this.name = '';
          this.website = '';
          this.registrationNumber = '';
          this.dateEstablished = null;
          this.address = '';
          this.country = [];
          this.companyLogo = '';
      }
    }
```

I got two errors:

1. > Object is possibly 'undefined' - and all the "this." highlighted
2. > Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128) - and the last closing curly brace highlighted.
3. > expected call-signature: 'clear' to have a typedef (typedef)tslint(typedef)

How do I get these resolve?

Thanks

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think an interface can contain a method implementation. Interfaces describe the members that should be present in the concrete implementation of the interface. They don't contain their definitions. Have you seen information that suggests otherwise?

Comment: @JLRishe - What's the best way to go about it. Kindly advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an implementation of that interface like this:

file: school.ts

```
interface ISchool {
      name: string = '';
      website: string;
      registrationNumber: string;
      dateEstablished: Date;
      address: string;
      country: [];
      companyLogo: any = '';
    
      clear(): () => void; 

    }


export class School implements ISchool {

      // Declare all attributes here;
      public name: string = '';
      ...

      clear() {
          this.name = '';
          this.website = '';
          this.registrationNumber = '';
          this.dateEstablished = null;
          this.address = '';
          this.country = [];
          this.companyLogo = '';
      }

}
```

file app.ts

```
import {School} from 'school.ts';

const someSchool = new School();
someSchool.clear();
```

This is a basic object orientation technic so i would recommend to look up the use of classes together with interfaces.

You dont need the interface if you only have one type of school though.

Comment: Which of the two (2) exports am I using? class or interface?

Comment: You have to instantiate an object of the class school like const someSchool = new School(); and then call someSchool.clear();

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you update the code?